# Conda fails to create environment from YML file do to UTF8

Tags: python, conda, environment

I am posting this, just in case someone else have the same issue.
I tried to share the my work environment with colleagues, [following these instructions](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file) and had some Errors.

The problem was that when you export the environment on Windows, conda creates a non UTF-8 encoded file, even though when you run `conda env create -f environment.yml` conda expects you to have an UTF-8 encoded file.

Answer (score 0):

To contour this, I converted the YML file to a UTF-8 encoded file (opened with Windows' notepad and changed the encoding).

Please, let me know if anyone else have a better solution for this.